# Only Adding New Table Data in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to read data off a few files and create a new document containing the read data, which is easy enough using the workbook object.

However, I'm not sure how to only add data which has not been added yet without overwriting the previously written data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the data being overwritten the same as the data replacing it?

Comment: For the most part yes, only each element of the list I create will have a timestamp corresponding to the time it was added to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read your data into a `Dictionary` object first. Dictionaries can be used to store a unique list of items. For example:

```
Dim d As Object
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' Loop thru your file data, adding each value if it doesn't exist...
    If Not d.Exists(strData) Then d.Add strData, ""
' End loop

' Now add each dictionary item to your workbook...
Dim k As Variant
For Each k In d
    ' Add k to workbook
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the dictionary object

Comment: Adding "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" to the VBA References adds the Dictionary object to IntelliType in the Editor which is handy if your learning about them. `CreateObject` is probably the best way over all as its more portable.